# Mocha with Promises, how to properly print assertion error?

Tags: node.js, promise, mocha.js

Basically if I do the following:

```
it('does something', () => {
  return request(app)
    .get('/endpoint')
    .expect(302);
});
```

If the endpoint crashes with a 500, mocha says "Timeout".

If I add an extra `.catch(err => console.log(err)` like this:

```
it('does something', () => {
  return request(app)
    .get('/endpoint')
    .expect(302)
    .catch(err => console.log(err);
});
```

It prints to console `Error: expected 302 "Found", got 500 "Internal Server Error"` properly. However, `console.log` feels incorrect. What's the proper way to print this to stdout

Comment: You're using https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest?